# Is there any way to get list of online users in network?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2003

we've a domain based wired network, I want to know how many users are online or when they used their computer, Is there any way to figure it out?

**PS : our clients are windows XP and our server is Windows Serer 2003**

Comment: you mean in the no.of users in your lan?

Comment: @Vignesh4303 yes their number and their name.

Comment: how many computers / users? How real time do you need it? All in all, no there is not but there are possible ways to approximate...

Comment: @AthomSfere we've nearly 300 computers/users

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to count exactly who is on the network, logged on. There are some ways to approximate it though.

If you have a Home drive share server, you can look at open sessions, and count each username once. This is probably as good as it gets.

You can query Active Directory for last modified user accounts / computer accounts and guess who logged in today. This would really only be useful if every one logs out or reboots at the end of every shift and if your shifts are uniform.

Depending on your network gear, you might be able to get an up/down connected etc. report from your switches. This is ugly messy and really tells you little though if the desktop is on.

If you use SCCM you might be able to craft a query to check the machines.

In PowerShell, you can loop through all possible machines (From AD, or by going through and IP range) and then run remote WMI queries to get what machines you can ping, and who is logged on, but again this could be skewed horribly if the person has been logged on all week / month but has also be Out of the office.

There are lots of ways to get some information, but your environment will have more to do with what works best than any suggestion I can come up with off the cuff.

Hopefully these will give you some ideas for what works in your company though.